# Basic Conv2d has different results with CUDA and CPU

Tags: python, pytorch, cuda, dtype

I tested a basic `Conv2d` operation but it has different results with CUDA and CPU.

When running with the CPU, the values are exactly 2.5600, 3.8400, 3.8400, ..., 3.8400, 3.8400, 2.5600.
However, when running with CUDA,
the values are 2.5587, 3.8381, 3.8381, ..., 3.8381, 3.8381, 2.5587.

And when I converted the dtype to FP64, it is fixed.
However default data type for Torch is known to be FP32.
In that case, is this issue unavoidable?

The Code is below:

```py
# %%
conv_test = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, padding=(1,1),bias=False,dtype=torch.float64)
conv_test.weight=torch.nn.Parameter (conv_test.weight*0+0.1)
conv_test.to(torch.device("cpu"))
conv_test.to(torch.device("cuda:0"))
# %%
dummy=torch.randn(10,64,8,8).to(torch.float64)
dummy=dummy*0+0.1
dummy=dummy.to(torch.device("cpu"))
dummy=dummy.to(torch.device("cuda:0"))

# %%
conv_test(dummy)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dot product of two single-precision floating point vectors yields different results in CUDA kernel than on the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924703/dot-product-of-two-single-precision-floating-point-vectors-yields-different-resu)

Comment: Also see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10107454)

Answer (score 1):

It's unavoidable due to the way floating point numbers are implemented.
For one, floating point arithmetic is not associative. You can verify it for yourself using something like this:

```
print((0.7 + (0.2 + 0.1)) == 1) # True
print(((0.7 + 0.2) + 0.1) == 1) # False
```

Although arithmetically the result should be the same, due to the way floating point arithmetic works, the order of summation matters.

In general, the same operator will be implemented differently on different types of hardware in order to make best use of that hardware's features. So, the actual order of arithmetic operations performed to compute `conv2d` will not be the same.

Lack of associativity is only one of the ways in which FP arithmetic can perform unexpectedly and may not even be the root cause of the actual difference you observe. But this is enough to understand that there's no reason to expect the outputs to match exactly.

You can read more about the way floating point values work [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)